# Is it good practice to use Range.SpecialCells together with an error handler?

Tags: excel, vba

When using [Range.SpecialCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) with a range that doesn't contain cells that match the criteria an error is thrown saying that no cells were found.

The most common solution to this issue is letting it happen and using an error handler to deal with it.

Is that the best known way to solve it or is there other solutions that might be as good or better which avoid using an error handler?

The only thing I can think of would be saving the first cell's value, then changing its value to one that matches the criteria so it avoids the error making it always match at least that one cell, then change the value back to its original value and check the matched range's address to see if it matched that one cell only or more.

A bad/slow solution would be to not make use of it at all and just use loops with checks.

Here's some simple sample code to demostrate a little how it works with the error handler:

```
Private Sub Procedure()

  Dim OriginalRange As Excel.Range
  Dim NewRange As Excel.Range

  Set OriginalRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C4")
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Set NewRange = OriginalRange.SpecialCells(Type:=Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, Value:=Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlNumbers)
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  If (VBA.Err.Number <> 1004) Then VBA.Err.Raise VBA.Err.Number

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly normal (I prefer this way) to use the error handler. What I do is, I sandwhich it between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` and then check `If NewRange is Nothing`

See this example

```
On Error Resume Next
Set NewRange = OriginalRange.SpecialCells(Type:=Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, _
                                          Value:=Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlNumbers)
On Error GoTo 0

If NewRange Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Your message here informing the USER that desired cells were not found"
Else
  '
  '~~> Do whatever you want with the range
  '
End If
```

Comment: Using `Resume Next` instead of `GoTo <Label>` does make the code look better I have to agree. Even though it doesn't check for the error's number to filter out ignoring any other errors (if there's even any other possible errors for that one line of code). Though it would be nice if the method returned `Nothing` straight away instead of throwing an error, and also that the error was documented in the API page instead of being found out about by new users of it when they encounter the error.